# infinite while loop issue on dice roll program

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, while-loop, dice

I have made this code for a project and i have run into a problem with the while loop becasue it just repeat the first input function, here is the code, i would aprriecate it if someone could  point out my problem and help me fix my code, thnx

```
import random
roll_agn='yes'
while roll_agn=='yes':
    dice=input ('Please choose a 4, 6 or 12 sided dice: ')
    if dice ==4:
        print(random.randint(1,4))
    elif dice ==6:
        print(random.randint(1,6))
    elif dice ==12:
        print(random.randint(1,12))
    else:
        roll_agn=input('that is not 4, 6 or 12, would you like to choose again, please answer yes or no') 
    if roll_agn !='yes':
        print ('ok thanks for playing')
```

Comment: Indent your `else:` to be inside the while loop and it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The else block of the while would be executed only if roll_agn became non-'yes' inside the loop. You never change it inside the while loop, so it loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement is unindented (outside of the loop), so the variable within is never reset, so the condition that the `while` loop requires is always `True`, hence an infinite loop. You just need to indent this:

```
elif dice ==12:
     ...
else:
^    roll_agn = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is off as others have pointed out. Here are a few suggestions on how to improve your code a little further

```
import random


while True:
    try:
        dice = int(input ('Please choose a 4, 6 or 12 sided dice: '))  # this input should be an int 
        if dice in (4, 6, 12):  # checks to see if the value of dice is in the supplied tuple
            print(random.randint(1,dice))
            choice = input('Roll again? Enter yes or no: ')
            if choice.lower() == 'no':  # use .lower() here so a match is found if the player enters No or NO
                print('Thanks for playing!')
                break  # exits the loop
        else:
            print('that is not 4, 6 or 12')
    except ValueError:  # catches an exception if the player enters a letter instead of a number or enters nothing
        print('Please enter a number')
```

This will work no matter what the player enters.